# Convert Azure Pipeline condition/variable to a json boolean

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

Currently, I'm working on a pipeline that should call an Azure Function in a certain way, depending on the outcome/result of a previous job in that pipeline.

The Azure Function should be called when the result of previous job is either: `Succeeded`, `SucceededWithIssues` or `Failed`. We want to ignore `Skipped` and `Cancelled`.

The body sent to the Azure Function differs based on the result: `Succeeded/SucceededWithIssues` VS `Failed`. It only differs by a single boolean in the payload called: `DeploymentFailed`.

The current implementation is using two separate tasks for calling the Azure Function. This was necessary, since I couldn't find a way to convert the outcome of the previous job to a boolean.

The current pipeline as is:

```
trigger:
- master

parameters:
  - name: jobA
    default: 'A'
  - name: correlationId
    default: '90c7e477-2141-45db-812a-019a9f88bdc8'

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:
  - job: job_${{parameters.jobA}}
    steps:
    - script: echo "This job could potentially fail."

  - job: job_B
    dependsOn: job_${{parameters.jobA}}
    variables:
      failed: $[dependencies.job_${{parameters.jobA}}.result]
    condition: in(variables['failed'], 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Failed')
    pool: server
    steps:
    - task: AzureFunction@1
      displayName: Call function succeeded
      condition: in(variables['failed'], 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues')
      inputs:
        function: "<azure-function-url>"
        key: "<azure-function-key>"
        method: 'POST'
        waitForCompletion: false
        headers: |
          {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
        body: |
          {
            "CorrelationId": "${{parameters.correlationId}}",
            "DeploymentFailed": false # I would like to use the outcome of `variable.failed` here and cast it to a JSON bool.
          }
    - task: AzureFunction@1
      displayName: Call function failed
      condition: in(variables['failed'], 'Failed')
      inputs:
        function: "<azure-function-url>"
        key: "<azure-function-key>"
        waitForCompletion: false
        method: 'POST'
        headers: |
          {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
        body: |
          {
            "CorrelationId": "${{parameters.correlationId}}",
            "DeploymentFailed": true # I would like to use the outcome of `variable.failed` here and cast it to a JSON bool.
          }
```

My question: How can I use the outcome of the previous job to only have 1 Azure Function invoke task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map condition directly to variable:

```
    variables:
      failed: $[dependencies.job_${{parameters.jobA}}.result]
      result: $[lower(notIn(dependencies.job_${{parameters.jobA}}.result, 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Failed'))]
```

and then:

```yaml
    - task: AzureFunction@1
      displayName: Call function succeeded
      condition: in(variables['failed'], 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues')
      inputs:
        function: "<azure-function-url>"
        key: "<azure-function-key>"
        method: 'POST'
        waitForCompletion: false
        headers: |
          {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
        body: |
          {
            "CorrelationId": "${{parameters.correlationId}}",
            "DeploymentFailed": $(result) # I would like to use the outcome of `variable.failed` here and cast it to a JSON bool.
          }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think it is close, but not quite there yet. This yields `True` or `False` depending on previous job. Which is not `true` or `false` (lower-case).

Comment: This is easy :) -add `lower()` I changed my reply :)

Comment: Perfect, I expected that the usage of `lower()` would turn the value type into a String instead of a boolean. But it actually works :)